# How to turn off query result reuse in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, query-optimization, benchmarking

I am trying to do some benchmarking for some query patterns. Multiple runs aren't very useful as snowflake returns the result immediately using QUERY RESULT REUSE node. Is there a way to force snowflake to re-compute the query?

Suspending and restarting a warehouse or using a new warehouse doesn't help with this.

Answer (score 2):

```sql
alter session set USE_CACHED_RESULT = FALSE
```

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer. You may change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the answer, at any time.

Comment: I still want the cache effects to exist while benchmarking because that's closer to what the real case looks like

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() as one of the projected columns. This forces the query optimizer to recompute results as the function isn't deterministic.